# graph/tree walking in python bridge of Koenigsberg

Tags: python, graph, tree

Given the following graph (from the bridge of Koenigsberg problem)

```
graph = { "a" : ["c", "d"],
          "b" : ["c", "d"],
          "c" : ["a", "b", "d"],
          "d" : ["a", "b", "c"]
        }
```

I am trying to create a loop with n iterations corresponding to the length of the walk given a particular starting nod.

Say for a walk of length two starting from node a we should get something like:

```
[["c", "d"],["a", "b", "d","a", "b", "c"], ["c", "d","c", "d","a", "b", "c","c", "d","c", "d","a", "b", "d"]]
```

First I need to append the links to each element of the starting node to get to the next level of the tree.

I have tried the following.

```
stnode = "a"
walk = list()
walk.append(graph[stnode])

for i in graph [stnode]:
    walk.append(graph[i])
    print walk
```

which returns

```
[['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
[['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

but I only need

```
[['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: "but it does not work": **terrible** problem description. Edit your question and clarify how it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: what is `start`? You don't mention it anywhere.

Comment: StackOverflow rule here is:
*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*

Comment: do you really want `[['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]`?  or `[['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c']]`?

Comment: ideally     [['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c']]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating only one list, and appending to that list.
Instead, you should have a main `walk` list, and you should also be creating a new list for each level, extending it with whatever is in the graph, and then appending that list to the `main` walk list.

```
stnode = "a"
walk = list()
walk.append(graph[stnode])

next_walk = list()
for i in graph [stnode]:
    next_walk.extend(graph[i])
walk.append(next_walk)
print walk
```

Here's how you might do the whole lot in one go:

```
walk_len = 2
start_node = 'a'
walk = [[start_node]]
for _ in range(walk_len+1):
    next_nodes = list()
    for node in walk[-1]:
        next_nodes.extend(graph[node])
    walk.append(next_nodes)
walk = walk[1:]
```